# How to hide the windows OS.default dark theme setting from chrome so that I can force sites to think `prefers-color-scheme` is `light`?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, themes

I want a dark theme for everything except READING DOCUMENTATION, so I have no choice but to set my OS default to **dark**. In most editors for documents and reading, the background is often still white, the surrounding masonry will still be dark which suits me great.

In chrome:

- I **disabled** the experimental flag to force-enable dark theme.
- Under appearance I **set my theme to light**.

But websites are still picking up in media queries that `prefers-color-scheme` is `dark`, which means chrome is still sending the OS default to browsers. How do I prevent it from using / see / propagating this value? Is it a chrome bug?